# Partially sort an SQL table according to column values

Tags: sql, sorting, shuffle

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

```
product, color
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 2
5, 2
6, 2
7, 3
8, 3
```

would it be possible to re-arrange the table such that products are re-arranged by color? For example, in this case the answer would be:

```
product, color
1, 1
4, 2
7, 3
2, 1
5, 2
8, 3
2, 1
6, 2
3, 1
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Answer, if any, will probably be product specific.

Comment: When you use the word "Shuffle", people will think you're looking for random results. What you're actually asking for is a custom "Sort".

Comment: fixed. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can order by NEWID()

Let's make the test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (product int, colour int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (product, colour)
VALUES
(1,1)
,(2,1)
,(3,1)
,(4,2)
,(5,2)
,(6,2)
,(7,3)
,(8,3)
```

Then run the query on this;

```
SELECT 
product
,colour
FROM #TestData
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Which gives a random order of the data like this;

```
product colour
4       2
1       1
5       2
7       3
6       2
3       1
2       1
8       3
```

Edit: I've just seen that you seem to want to order with some pattern in the colour column, not random. I'm going to leave this answer anyway as a random result.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I need the initial ordering. That is, product 1 should be the first etc...

Comment: it's a re-arranging based on color

Answer (score 0):

I would select a random number as third column and sort by that random number. In pseudo code:

```
SELECT PRODUCT,
       COLOR,
       RANDOM_NUMBER()
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY 3
```

The generation of a random number depends on your database. In Oracle, it would be `dbms_random.random`.

You can get rid of the random number by re-selecting from the table as follows:

```
SELECT PRODUCT,
       COLOR
FROM  (SELECT PRODUCT,
              COLOR,
              RANDOM_NUMBER()
       FROM   YOUR_TABLE
       ORDER BY 3)
```

Comment: Doesn't OP want 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: The OP talks about shuffling :-)

Comment: Yes, I know, but 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 seems like an odd random order.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I need ordering

Comment: Hmm, please specify in detail what your requirements are. It is apparently not a simple ordering by color.

Comment: I need to re-arrange the products so that consecutive colors are always different, keeping the initial ordering when possible.

Comment: I suspect that this problem cannot be solved using SQL alone. Furthermore, this problem does not have a solution in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for row_number:

```
SELECT product, colour, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY product)
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY 3, 2
```